# Update destination namespace of argocd application

Tags: openshift, argocd

I'm trying to use ArgoCD applicationSet to deploy the same application to different namespaces on the same cluster.

I have two repo: "resources", containing the helm chart of resources to be generated (think deployments, configMaps, Pvc, etc.) with per-namespace customizations and "resources-config", containing some parameters that might change from time to time.

The "resources-config" is structured as follows:

```
resources-config
  `-- per-namespace-config
     `-- ns-one
        `-- config.yaml
     `-- ns-two
        `-- config.yaml
     `-- ...
```

The idea is that the **destination namespaces** of the resources are taken from the folder structure of the "resources-config" repository, so `ns-one`, `ns-two`, etc.

The applicationSet is as follows:

```yml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: my-appset
  namespace: openshift-gitops
spec:
  generators:
    - git:
        files:
          - path: per-namespace-config/*/config.yaml
        repoURL: <redacted>/resources-config
        revision: main
  syncPolicy:
    preserveResourcesOnDeletion: false
  template:
    metadata:
      name: 'myapp-{{ path.basename }}'
    spec:
      destination:
        ###
        namespace: '{{ path.basename }}{{ namespaceSuffix }}'
        ### 
        server: <redacted>
      project: my-resources
      source:
        path: 'resources/'
        repoURL: <redaced>/resources
        targetRevision: main
        helm:
          # Release name override (defaults to application name)
          releaseName: '{{ path.basename }}-svi'
          valueFiles:
            - 'per-namespace/{{ path.basename }}/values.yaml'

          # Ignore locally missing valueFiles when installing Helm chart. Defaults to false
          ignoreMissingValueFiles: false
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: false
          selfHeal: true
        syncOptions:
        - CreateNamespace=false
        - Prune=false
```

To enable deploying on a test namespace, the file `config.yaml` contains a field `namespaceSuffix` that may be empty or equal to `-test`

```yaml
namespaceSuffix: -test
```

The idea is that I deploy the resources on test namespaces, and after checking that everything is OK, I change the `namespaceSuffix` to blank and resources are created on "production" namespace.

So my flow is:

1. create ApplicationSet (oc apply -f applicationSet.yaml) → resources are created in test namespaces
2. change config.yaml by putting `namespaceSuffix` to blank
3. commit & push
4. Sync apps → I expect that resources are created on "production" namespace.

**However, the destination namespace does not change and no resources are created on the "production" namespace.**

Replacing (oc replace) the applicationSet after the push does not make any difference.

Is there a way to update the destination namespace (after creation of the applicationSet) based on some parameters used in the AppSet generator?